# How do I pull specific strings out of the standard output of netsh?

Tags: c#, regex, list, netsh

I am using `netsh` to check saved wireless profiles and their encryption status. I can capture the output of `netsh` like this:

```
   private void wifiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show profiles";
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.Start();
        //* Read the output (or the error)
        string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        textBox3.Text = output;
        cmd.WaitForExit();          
    }
```

The results return in a textbox which look like this:

```
Profiles on interface Wi-Fi:

Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
<None>

User profiles
-------------
All User Profile     : GuestFSN
All User Profile     : CorporateWifi
All User Profile     : ATT3122
```

I want to pull out the wireless profile names (GuestFSN, CorporateWifi, ATT3122, etc...) and put them into a list. How do I do this in C#?

Comment: So what exactly your question? Something like "Does C# string class has `IndexOf`?" or "Use regular expression to find string"...

Comment: `limitations of C#` - there's no such thing. Whatever you're doing via the command line is probably calling into Win32 APIs,  which you can access from C# code using P/Invoke. I have no idea what you mean by "limitations of C#".

Comment: there is WAAAAY more to be done to have the administrative access built into the app, then run the Native-Wifi API to get the wireless data, then after that I still cant query saved wireless profile data to its fullest extent from the research I have done. Where as this, seems fairly straight forward. I run netsh, get the profile names, isolate names into a list, then BAM run them one by one through netsh again.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Essentially I want to remove all string data except what comes behind each of the "All User Profile     :" then take each of the remaining strings and break them into a list. (I am not the greatest at programing and am still teaching myself so I apologize for sounding like a fool)

Comment: @JoePearson I edited your question to clarify your request and remove some of the assumptions that others found contentious above. Feel free to roll back my edit if you feel it changed your underlying meaning.

Comment: @NateBarbettini sorry for my verbose post lol I am a writer by trade so i tend to over state myself. Thank you for the edit, it is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Regular Expressions](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match). Regex allows you to define a pattern to look for in a larger string. This will allow you to pull a list of strings (network names) out of the string you get back from standard output.

To match the pattern "All User Profile [whitespace]: [name]", you can use this regex pattern:

> `All User Profile[\s]+: (.*)`

A match is found in the larger string for this pattern if these conditions are met:

- The literal string "All User Profile" occurs
- Followed by one or more whitespace characters - `[\s]+`)
- Followed by a colon and a space
- Followed by a string of undetermined length - `(.*)` (but ending with a newline)

You can test this regular expression pattern using a tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Here's a code sample for your scenario:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"All User Profile[\s]+: (.*)");
var resultList = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(output))
{
    resultList.Add(match.Groups[1]);
}
```

A `foreach` loop is used so that we can deal with one or many results from `regex.Matches` and add all of them into the result list.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vhkUV5

Comment: ill put this into play when i get back to my PC at work. I remember learning about this when i was studying and completely forgot about it! lol ill have to go back to that module and relearn it. If this works Ill repost the code and owe you 50 IRL Karma points. lol major thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    // output would be set by earlier code
    var output = @"Profiles on interface Wi-Fi:

Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
   <None>

  User profiles
  -------------
            All User Profile     : GuestFSN
            All User Profile     : CorporateWifi
            All User Profile     : ATT3122";

    var regex = new Regex(@"All User Profile[\s]+: (.*)");
    var resultList = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(output))
    {
        resultList.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", resultList));
}
}
```

Comment: Since this is available in the fiddle above, it doesn't really need to be in a separate answer.

Comment: Webdesign rule number one, any time the user doesn't have to leave the website make it possible. lol I just wanted to make it convenient for future users.